# jquery-ui: immediate draggable on mousedown

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, mousedown

Working with jQuery-UI, it is possible to make an element draggable by applying .draggable() method on *mousedown* event. And then drag it on another mouse press (and drag).
Is it possible to make element draggable and start dragging immediately by single mouse press (mousedown event).

*What happens*:

1) press blue rect and try to drag (element not movable);

2) unpress rect and try to drag again (element is movable).

*What should happen*:

1) press blue rect and drag it --> element is movable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>draggable() on press</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
        <style>#rect{ border: 1px dotted blue; width:100px; height:100px; background-color: lightblue;}</style>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log('document is ready');
                $('#rect').mousedown(function(ev){
                    console.log(ev.target.id+' pressed');
                    $(ev.target).draggable();
                    // $(this).draggable(); // Works the same.
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='rect'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-trigger the `mousedown` event after the widget initialization. You can use `.trigger` for this:

```
$('#rect').mousedown(function(ev){
    console.log(ev.target.id+' pressed');
    if ( !$(ev.target).data("ui-draggable") ) {
        $(ev.target).draggable();
        $(ev.target).trigger(ev);
    }
});
```

Note the draggable data check: you have to only do this ONCE (or you'd get a re-initialised widget and possibly infinite event trigger recursion)

Also, this is the default behaviour if you only just the widget draggable (eg. on document-ready)

```
$("#rect").draggable();
```

and not bother with `mousedown` at all. This is what you should do unless you have very good reason to insist on using the event, which isn't mentioned in the question

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ame9ege/